# How do you subtract the current time from the time five minutes ago?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a time from five minutes ago, using `datetime.time.now()` and I need to know what the time would be if I subtracted that time from the current time.

Try 1 - Didn't Work:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time1 = datetime.now()
time2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)

print(time1 - time2)
```

This gave me "-1 day, 23:54:59.999987".

Try 2 - Worked, but is there a better way?:

```
time1 = datetime.now()
time2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)

print(str(time1 - time2).split(',')[1])
```

This gave me the desired result, but is there a method besides string manipulation?

Comment: One time minus another time will give you a difference in time (timedelta).  That makes logical sense.  I'm not sure what you are asking? Give example times for input and output that you expect please.

Comment: Won't that always result in 5 minutes...?

Comment: @gmds, he wants to subs the resulted time from current. it's not our epoch.

Comment: why the first way you suppose doesn't work? it gives a correct time

Comment: This question makes no sense, the difference will always be -5m

Comment: Calculate `time2-time1`

Comment: In the real code, the time difference could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanted to take an advice how to use a `time` object?

Well, if you want to specify a format of string representation of your time, just use [strftime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime)

Example below:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time1 = datetime.now()
time2 = datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=5)

print((time1 - time2).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the time 5 minutes ago, you can use `timedelta` without any string manipulation:

```
five_min_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes = 5)
```

Comment: This isn't my original code. In the original one, the difference could be anything, I only now the starting time, and the current time.